# SQL Server 2008 R2: Updating past dates to the 'next' date

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2. I have a table with lots of dates, some in the past, some in the future. What I would like to do would be to update them so the dates are the 'next' date, relative to today.

For example given the current date is '2014-02-09'

```
Current Value     Desired Value
-------------------------------------------------    
'2010-01-06'      '2015-01-06' (Updated to 2015)
'2008-03-28'      '2014-03-28' (Updated to 2014)
```

I'd need to account for dates on 29th of Feb, just to make this easier!

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Calculate the number of years between today and x and then add that number of years to x.

Comment: @dnoeth: that doesn't take into account that the resulting date can be earlier than the "current date" in which case the next year must be taken (look at the first row).

Comment: @Tim Schmelter: Yep, it's the number of years (i.e. age) plus one :-)

Comment: @dnoeth: depends on the resulting date if he needs to add 0 or 1 years.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter: if you calculate the full number of years (aka age) it's like getting the next birthday. I posted an answer to show it.

Answer (score 1):

You can determine who many years in the past the date is.  Then add that number of years plus one to the date:

```
update t
    set datecol = dateadd(year,
                          datediff(year, datecol, getdate()) + 1,
                          datecol)
    where datecol < getdate();
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
Declare @CurrentDate datetime
SET @CurrentDate = '2014-02-09'

;WITH NewDatesThisYear AS
(
    SELECT [Date], 
           NewDate = DateAdd(yy, YEAR(@CurrentDate)-1900,  
                     DateAdd(m,  MONTH([Date]) - 1, DAY([Date]) - 1)) 
    FROM dbo.Dates
)
, NewDates AS
(
    SELECT [Date], 
           NewDate = CASE WHEN NewDate < @CurrentDate 
                     THEN DateAdd(yy, 1,NewDate) 
                     ELSE NewDate END
    FROM NewDatesThisYear
)
UPDATE NewDates SET [Date] = NewDate
WHERE [Date] < @CurrentDate
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d9212/7/0)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

untested:

```
CASE WHEN dateadd(yy, datecol, datediff(yy, datecol, getdate())) > getdate()
     THEN dateadd(yy, datecol, datediff(yy, datecol, getdate()))
     ELSE dateadd(yy, datecol, datediff(yy, datecol, getdate())+1)
END
```

This would be so much easier if SQL Server supported a simple age calculation :-)

```
dateadd(yy, datecol, age(datecol, getdate()) +1)
```